# Differentiating between different versions of a game

Tags: discussion

A Game Of Thrones: The Card Game is getting a major reboot in the coming months. Although similarities are going to exist between the current and new version, there will also be major changes. What approach is taken?

Do we just create a new tag for the new version e.g. [game-of-thrones-lcg-2ed](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones-lcg-2ed)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that a new tag is necessary. For example for Axis and Allies we only have the one [axis-and-allies](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axis-and-allies) even though there are several different version of the game with different rules. We would do the same thing with A Game of Thrones: The Card Game, if the edition matters include it in the question, if the asker doesn't include it add a comment asking which version they are asking about.